# nexus proxy repository for npm registry 2fa enabled

Tags: npm, nexus, nexus3

I have a issue with nexus and npm registry.
we publish private node packages to "https://www.npmjs.com/" and our account has 2fa enabled.
We also need to download public node packages. And we use npm auth token to access private node packages.
Now in order to make package download faster, we use nexus. 
I don't see any documentation how to use auth token in nexus. There's guide on using username/password but we also have 2fa enabled in our npm account. I'm stuck here.

client (npmrc points to private nexus repository) -> nexus repository (I don't know how to configure auth token here, or how to use it with npm 2fa authentication enabled)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no current way to do what you ask.
I believe https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-17372 may be what you desire.  If so, you can follow and vote for that ticket to show interest.